# How to query excel file in C# using a detailed query

Tags: c#, excel

The following code returns data from a spreadsheet into a grid perfectly

```
[
        string excelConnectString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            "Data Source = " + excelFileName + ";" +
            "Extended Properties = Excel 8.0;";

        OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectString);
        OleDbCommand objCmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [Accounts$]", objConn);

        OleDbDataAdapter objDatAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        objDatAdap.SelectCommand = objCmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        objDatAdap.Fill(ds);
        fpDataSet_Sheet1.DataSource = ds;//fill a grid with data
]
```

The spreadsheet I'm using has columns named from A and so on( just standard column names )
and the sheet name is Accounts.

I have a problem with the query ...

```
  [OleDbCommand objCmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [Accounts$]", objConn);]
```

How can I make the query string like this...

```
"Select <columnA>,<columnB>,SUM<columnG> from [Accounts$] group by <columnA>,<columnB>"
```

..so that it returns the results of this query

Note : columnA is A on Sheet , columnB is B on Sheet and columnG is G on Sheet

Other possible Alternatives:

1. I have the data of that excel spread into a DataTable object, how can I query the DataTAble object
2. I read about a DataView object that it can take a table and return the table manipulated according to (`<dataviewObject>.RowFilter = "where..."`) , but I don't know how to use the query I want.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want something like:

```
 SELECT Sum([NameOfFieldAsPerHeader]) FROM [Accounts$]
```

Or

```
 SELECT [ForExampleEmployeeID], Sum([NameOfFieldAsPerHeader]) FROM [Accounts$]
 GROUP BY [ForExampleEmployeeID]
```

Or

```
 SELECT [ForExampleEmployeeID], Year([SomeDate]), Sum([NameOfFieldAsPerHeader]) 
 FROM [Accounts$]
 GROUP BY [ForExampleEmployeeID], Year([SomeDate])
```

Or

```
 SELECT [ForExampleEmployeeID], Year([SomeDate]), Sum([NameOfFieldAsPerHeader]) 
 FROM [Accounts$]
 WHERE Year([SomeDate])>2000
 GROUP BY [ForExampleEmployeeID], Year([SomeDate])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do **Group by** then DataTable class has a method called **Compute**  that executes few SQL functions. 
The following functions are supported :  **COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG, STDEV, VAR**.

```
string salary = empTable.Compute("SUM( Salary )", "").ToString();
string averageSalaryJan = empTable.Compute("AVG( Salary )", "Month = 1").ToString();
// Assuming you have month stored in Month column and Salary stored in Salary column
```

Other alternatives you can explore are:

1. You may use the Microsoft KB article [HOW TO: Implement a DataSet GROUP BY Helper Class in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326145)
2. If you are using .NET 3.5 you may use Linq ref : [LINQ DataTable Query - Group Aggregation](http://weblogs.asp.net/wenching/archive/2008/05/16/linq-datatable-query-group-aggregation.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, does `SUM` represent a potential column name or a SQL funciton?

Are you trying to get your query so that you're able to reference `Column A, B, C, D, etc...` from the Excel sheet as `ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, etc...` in your SQL query?

I suppose I mean:  do you want to write your `query` as this:  `Select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC from [Accounts$]`, rather than this:  `Select * from [Accounts$]` ?

If so, you can put column headers in the first row of your Excel sheet and treat those as the column names in the `connection string`.  To do this, make your `connection string` line look like this:

```
excelConnectString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source = " 
+ excelFileName + ";" + "Extended Properties = Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;";
```

The different is the `HDR=Yes` portion in the Extended Properties section.  Once you're able to reference the columns in your Excel sheet by using column names, you should be able to use DataTable's `Select` method and `DataView's RowFilter property` as you mentioned.

Does this help or even address your question?