# Possible easy way to convert data in Excel to store as objects in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have few Excel files that contain three columns of data(numbers only) that I would like to store as C# objects. These objects will then be used to populate a Report chart in Visual Studio. Is there an easy way to convert  this data to objects in C#? So, I would like to import this data into a list or collection in C#. Then use this list to create a chart.

I have looked around and there seem to be external libraries that read/write to Excel files but I am not in favor of external libraries. Also, I would like to point out that I am not using mysql. I am creating objects in memory and populating my report in Visual Studio with these objects.

Thank you!

Comment: Apparently there's a LINQ to Excel provider - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd920313(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: If the Excel files don't have to remain Excel files, you convert them to CSV.

Otherwise, Visual Studio Tools for Office may be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The method here works for me :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37164563/4573839

Use it and you can turn Excel into `DataTable`, Then just use the [**General Way**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208532/how-do-you-convert-a-datatable-into-a-generic-list) to turn the Rows and Columns of DataTable into Object's Property,

For exapmle suppose `dr` is one of the DataRow, you can get data by  `dr["ColumnName"]`, and the ColumnName possibly is the upmost cell of the column in  Excel Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for reading Excel Files and converting the data into .NET objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL queries in your Excel files and use the results to populate your object (or your reports directly), for more info take a look here: [How to query excel file in C# using a detailed query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207693/how-to-query-excel-file-in-c-sharp-using-a-detailed-query)

Comment: I know, but it's a way to use Excel as a SQL database.